# WPF Close parent dialog while opening a child dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core

This is the intended flow:

Login dialog opens -> User enters username and clicks next -> Login dialog closes -> Domain dialog opens -> User enters Domain name and Password -> If correct, Domain dialog closes

However, currently what happens is that I go through the login dialog and when I click next, the domains dialog opens but the previous dialog is still open.

I cannot use windows because this login sequence is stopping the actual MainWindow from loading until the user is authenticated. Or is there a better way of doing this?

The login sequence is referenced from another project.

This is how I call a new dialog in my Login dialog:

```
Domain domain = new Domain(configuration, Username);
domain.ShowDialog();
domain.Owner = this;
this.Owner.Hide();
this.Close();
```

Comment: Try to open domain dialog in MainWindow, if login success, login dialog close itself by return DialogResult. Then MainWindow know login finish, open domain dialog.

Comment: Is it not possible to do it like the intended flow?

Comment: I think the flow is same, just change "domain dialog" showdialog calling from "login dialog" to MainWindow

Comment: I can't do that because Login dialog passes Username to Domain dialog. I can set it in the App.Current.Properties but I don't want to resort to that.

Comment: You can do this without App.Current.Properties, set public variable username in Login dialog, MainWindow can get username pass to Domain dialog.

Comment: I see. I'll go with this suggestion then. Thank you for your help. Can you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to open Domain dialog in MainWindow, set public variable username in Login dialog. Then MainWindow can get username pass to Domain dialog.